# Scripting via in Eagle library

Tags: eaglecad

I am trying to create a custom library part in Eagle and I am having trouble scripting vias.  I get an error saying that vias can only be created for boards. However I can manually place them with my mouse.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: @Leon I disagree. Designing parts in Eagle (or any schematic/PCB software) is *definitely* part of electronic design.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "scripting vias".

Comment: using the command line and typing "VIA diameter location" will not work in the library designer.  I can however use the mouse and place them. I need to place dozens of them at precise locations so its tough to use a mouse. It gives me an error saying I can place VIAs in the board designer window on a project when using the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you cannot place vias in a package design.

Instead of it you can use pads with different shapes.

You can use the tool on the left or you can use the command like this:

PAD [diameter] [shape]

For a round pad (like a via) you can type:

pad 1.2mm round